Image URL syntax
I am trying to make a background image in a java jframe window, but when I try to initialize it, I get a null pointer exception saying the location url I put in is null.
I've tried the following:

introbg = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("../images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();
introbg = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();
introbg = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("file:///D:/Users/calac/eclipse-workspace/interesting/images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();


Does this answer your question? Class path resource for JLabel ImageIcon

Note .. is not supported by getResource (it incidentally works in some circumstances, but not all).

Where is introBackground.jpg located in your project? Are you using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle? Does the IDE recognize an ancestor directory of your JPEG as a "resource root"? Is the JPEG ending up in the build output (i.e., is it placed on the class-path/module-path at run-time)?

Per the documentation getResource uses the module's class loader. The class loader is configurable by subclassing ClassLoader. Evidentially whichever class  loader is configured in your development environment doesn't allow creating resource URLs for images on disk, at least not with strings as as you have formatted them.
Luckily, ImageIcon has another constructor that takes a filename, so you can try using these instead:
introbg = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("D:/Users/calac/eclipse-workspace/interesting/images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();

introbg = new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("images/introBackground.jpg")).getImage();

Note that these are file paths, so if you know that you need resource paths, then these options may not be useful to you.

The first of those three is not a resource path but a file path. The second has been commented on above and should be avoided

I’ve removed the ../ option now, and mentioned that these are file paths.
